# Non-existent param "Fingerprint" in google contactsGroup api

Tags: google-contacts-api, google-people-api

I'm trying to update the label in google contacts using the method from the docs
https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups/update

Got a response

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Fingerprint is missing.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Even though Google API Explorer

[image]

How solve this, maybe someone can help. What does this Fingerprint mean? I can create/delete label but not update!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include the `etag`.

If you go to [Method: contactGroups.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups/get) or the [Method: contactGroups.list](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups/list), on the response you will find the groups 'etag'

Then on the [Method: contactGroups.update](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups/update) request body you set the new name you want the group to have and also include the `etag` like this:

```json
{
  "contactGroup": {
    "name": "newOne2",
    "etag": "r*****k="
  }
}
```